FastAPI SSE working Locally but not in Azure Web App?
We set up a basic notification system using SSE from our FastAPI server which seems to work fine locally, but doesn't work when we push it to our Azure Web App? I have server logs where I can see the notification is sent and consumed, but we can't see it being recieved on the frontend? I've looked around and seen discussion about turning off response buffering, but can't seem to figure out WHERE to do that (where can I find web.config's equivalent for our proj? We use containers if that helps?).
Here's a brief example of how the route looks:
@router.get(
    "/stream-notifs",
    response_description="User task notifications",
    response_model=Response,
    tags=["users"],
)
async def notif_update_stream(request: Request, user_id: str):

    MESSAGE_STREAM_DELAY = 1  # second
    MESSAGE_STREAM_RETRY_TIMEOUT = 15000  # milisecond

    client_host = request.client.host
    print(f"Client {client_host} connected.")

    async def event_generator():
        notif_q: asyncio.Queue = request.state.notif_q
        this_user_notifs = []

        while True:
            notif_data: NotificationData = await notif_q.get()

            if notif_data.creator_id == UUID(user_id):
                # TODO: Add validation
                this_user_notifs.append(notif_data)
                print(f"Sending to: {request.client}")
            else:
                notif_q.put_nowait(notif_data)

            # If client was closed the connection
            if await request.is_disconnected():
                break

            # Checks for new messages and return them to client if any
            for curr_notif in this_user_notifs:  # Whenever a task is completed
                notif = Notification(
                    id="message_id",
                    event="completed_task",
                    retry=MESSAGE_STREAM_RETRY_TIMEOUT,
                    data=curr_notif,
                ).model_dump_json()
                yield notif
                this_user_notifs.pop()
                notif_q.task_done()
                print(f"Finished notif {notif}")

            await asyncio.sleep(MESSAGE_STREAM_DELAY)

        await notif_q.join()

    return EventSourceResponse(
        event_generator(),
        media_type="text/event-stream",
        headers={
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "X-Accel-Buffering": "no",
        },
    )

The team is pretty new to Azure, so there's probably something I missed here. The backend is hosted on a container on a web app like I mentioned, and the frontend is the same (Vue). Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!
As mentioned, I tried finding the settings to disable response buffering, looked for web.config, added the X-Accel-Buffering and Cache-Control headers but to no avail.

is CORS working fine?

@VivekVaibhavShandilya Absolutely. Even tried allowing all routes temporarily - no avail. Weirdly, if I spam the send notif route 3x times, the frontend gets the notification? I'm almost certain it has to do with buffering somewhere.

According to this reply, setting the header 'X-Accel-Buffering': 'no' might help. I have not tried it (nor ever used Azure), so no guarantees.

@M.O. Oof, already tried that - didn't seem to do anything. Just using a websocket instead for now I suppose...

@spook Have you tried checking by opening backend app url it is sending message outside the container? is FAST API is running on default port 8000? and can you share the port number mentioned in main container of Azure web app. you can check it in Deployment Centre of the container web app.

@VivekVaibhavShandilya Yep. Literally everything works and checks out. I even tried deploying it on another web app without a container, same thing. Sometimes it works, and I can get responses - other times, I have to spam it several times, and usually, I get nothing at all. It's super odd

@spook can you share your repo if possible?

@spook I am not sure on this but If its working only sometimes, chances are azure app service computation is reaching threasholds due to which  it may be breaking in between.

As I mentioned in comment if web app is not working sometimes in normal app service and you have to spam it.

Make sure App service computation is not reaching threshold.
Upgrade your app service plan which can handle computation.

I have Created a simple SSE in Fast API and deployed to Azure web app and its working perfectly fine for me.
I have enabled CORS.
main.py:
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from sse_starlette.sse import EventSourceResponse
import asyncio
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"], 
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"], 
    allow_headers=["*"], 
)

@app.get("/stream")
async def stream(request: Request):
    async def event_generator():
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            yield {"event": "message", "data": "Hello, World!"}

    return EventSourceResponse(event_generator())

uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

requirements.txt:
fastapi
sse-starlette
uvicorn

Deployed another web app with simple html file for client to receive event.
index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>SSE Example</h1>
    <div id="messages"></div>

    <script>
        const eventSource = new EventSource("https://fastapisse.azurewebsites.net/stream");

        eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
            const messageDiv = document.getElementById("messages");
            messageDiv.innerHTML += `<p>${event.data}</p>`;
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>

OUTPUT:
Locally:


Azure:
Fast Api web app

Client receiving event

